# How do I add a line break every 3 lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

My Notepad++ file is as such:

```
1
yyy                          
xxx
2
yyy
xxx
3
yyy
xxx
```

I want it to be like this:

```
1
yyy                          
xxx

2
yyy
xxx

3
yyy
xxx
```

How do I make it add a line break every 3 lines to look like that? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps (with cursor at start of file)...

1. Macro->"Start Recording" (from menu)
2. Press down arrow 3 times then ENTER
3. Macro->"Stop Recording" (from menu)
4. Then Macro->"Run a macro multiple times" then choose number of times or "Run until the end of the file".

Hope that helps!

Note: As pointed out in comments this method requires word wrap to be turned off.

Comment: Why to use macro when you can use Regexp replacing?

Comment: Regex works too.  It relies on the text/pattern matching his example with no exceptions.  This will put a line break every 3 lines regardless of the text.

Comment: So, with text in one line longer than window width and Line Wrap turned on, your method will not work....

Answer (score 3):

Have a try with:

Find what: `((?:[^\r\n]+(\R)){3})`
Replace with: `$1$2`

This will add a linebreak (the same one that is present on other lines) after 3 lines.

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start capture group 1
  (?:           : start non-capture group
    [^\r\n]+    : 1 or more non linebreak
    (\R)        : a linebreak, captured in group 2
  ){3}          : repeat 3 times the non capture group
)               : end group 1
```

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak ie. `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Replace Tool` (Ctrl + H), use Regular epression mode.

What to find: `(^[0-9]*$)`

Replace with: `\r\n\1`

That is all. You are using backreference to accepted pattern (that is `\1`)

You can find more examples at http://markantoniou.blogspot.cz/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html.